# Don't have SSL .key file for Nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl

I am setting Laravel Nginx Server up to subdomain.domain.com

I have gotten the .zip file with the SSL files inside but all I have is `xyz.crt`, `xyz.pem` and `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`. Nginx is failing to restart with the error

`cannot load certificate key "/etc/nginx/certificates/xyz.pem": PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey() failed`

I know that I am attempting the .pem file at the moment but this is me trying all the files (apart from the bundle as it seems to just have 3 certificates inside). Here is my Nginx config file so far

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.subdomain.domain.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certificates/xyz.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/xyz.pem;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    root /var/www/Project/public;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    error_page 404 /index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I have been stuck researching this for a while and have bitten the bullet to post a question. If there is an answer I can try please let me know

Comment: You already have it. You must. You used it to generate the CSR. You didn't send it to the CA (at least I hope not) and you didn't get it back from them. If you can't find it you will just have to create a new key pair, a new CSR, and get a new certificate bundle from the CA. Off topic.

Comment: This is not programming or development, but: exactly how was this 'gotten'? The correct sequence is (1) you generate privatekey and CSR, (2) you submit CSR to CA and provide domain proofs and pay if applicable, (3) CA, in this case GoDaddy, creates cert and gives it to you along with chain (which GD calls bundle), (4) you use privatekey from step 1 with cert+chain from step 3. Your zip file is step 3; you need to go back to step 1. (See item 2 in https://www.godaddy.com/help/nginx-install-a-certificate-6722 .)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my thanks goes to @dave_thompson_085 (upvoted comment on post)

For those using a GoDaddy Certificate and need to get the key, what they don't tell you in the same article is you can get your private key from cPanel if you have access to hosting. I was lucky to as it was a subdomain. Go to home->SSL->PrivateKeys and for me it was the latest in the folder.

If Dave's comment gets buried, this is the link they shared

[GoDaddy Install SSL with Nginx](https://godaddy.com/help/nginx-install-a-certificate-6722)

Can't thank them enough :)